# How to get values('content_object')?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I use standard django.contrb.comments app...

#### django/contrib/comments/models.py

```
class BaseCommentAbstractModel(models.Model):
    """
    An abstract base class that any custom comment models probably should
    subclass.
    """

    # Content-object field
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,
            verbose_name=_('content type'),
            related_name="content_type_set_for_contrib_%(class)s")
    object_pk = models.TextField(_('object ID'))
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey(ct_field="content_type", fk_field="object_pk")
    ...
```

and need to get list of comments with related objects tied through generic relations:

#### views.py

```
from django.contrib.comments import Comment

comment_list = list(Comment.objects.values_list('id', 'content_object')
```

but it throws an error:

> FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'content_object' into field. Choices are: comment, content_type, flags, id, ip_address, is_public, is_removed, object_pk, site, submit_date, user, user_email, user_name, user_url

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Show the Comment and relation models please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`content_object` is `GenericForeignKey` field. You should speficy `object_pk` (fk_field) instead:

```
Comment.objects.values_list('id', 'object_pk')
```

**UPDATE**

To get comment ids, url for objects:

```
[(pk, urlresolvers.reverse('comments-url-redirect', args=(ct, o)))
 for pk, o, ct in Comment.objects.values_list('id', 'object_pk', 'content_type')]
```

Comment: I need exactly id, not model instance, so it's ok. The Comment model is from django.contrib.comments and it has standard content_type field for ContentType, so it's also ok. I just tried to specify 'content_type__content_object' in command shell, but got the same error.

Comment: Yes, 'object_pk' works. But how to get an object, not pk? Or at least its 'get_absolute_url' method?

Comment: @VladT., To get url, you need to get `content_type`. And: `urlresolvers.reverse("comments-url-redirect", args=(content_type_id, object_pk))`

Comment: @VladT., https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.7.x/django/contrib/comments/models.py#L34

Comment: Thanks for the hint! But it seems that there is no way to use it to get the list by means of queryset API. The only way I can think of is to iterate the queryset in a loop.

Comment: @VladT., `Comment` model isntance can refer any model. You need to retrieve `content_type` anyway to know which model the comment refer.

Comment: Thank you for having time to help me! But what do you mean? Do you agree that I can't get a list of ids and urls with values_list()?

Comment: Bingo! That's what I need, thank you again! P.S. There is a type in your comment - urlresolver*s*.reverse()

Comment: @VladT., Thank you for pointing that. I updated the answer to include the list comprehension.